# Is this overfitting

Tags: data-science

I’m running a machine learning algorithm to answer True/False questions.
Assuming I use classification algo.
After running 1200 data, I got 30% of accuracy.

But then, I made a second algorithm to always negate the first algorithm’s answer
Thus it’s accuracy is 70%

Is this an overfitting for the second algo? Assuming my 1st algorithm consistenly predicts 30% accuracy

Comment: What are the features of your data and the graph outputted it may help? But based on my knowledge of ML I would say 70% is good. But 30% might be under fitting check this thread out maybe https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/278882/is-an-overfitted-model-necessarily-useless

Comment: Wow your thread that you sent is very informative! So let me elaborate my work a bit... so there are a bunch sets of True/False question. Algo 1 can predict either w/ 30% accuracy or 70% accuracy depending the subject of the questions. If it has 30% accuracy, Algo 2 will negate the answer of Algo 1. Assuming it’s not underfitted (i’ll look into this later), is Algo 2 practically a bad thing? Or Overfitting? Or is it good indeed? Because if i combine both of them, they will have 70% accuracy

Comment: My point is... if a Machine Learning algorithm can be so good at consistently making mistakes... isn’t it indeed great just to negate the answer?

Comment: I feel like this answer kind of depends on the machine learning model which you choose and the training set. Most ML Models make mistakes initially. In your case if the training set of Algo 2 is 70% it might mean that it is good at predicting the wrong thing? If i'm understanding this correctly? All though this might be true in the beginning of the data negating a ML answer is a bad idea. The better idea is to prepare your data correctly and train it on a data set which is the best fit for your model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To your questions. 
I feel like this answer kind of depends on the machine learning model which you choose and the training set. Most ML Models make mistakes initially. In your case if the training set of Algo 2 is 70% it might mean that it is good at predicting the wrong thing? If i'm understanding this correctly? All though this might be true in the beginning of the data negating a ML answer is a bad idea. The better idea is to prepare your data correctly and train it on a data set which is the best fit for your model.

Most Machine learning models make mistakes it is bound to happen. But the training set and all that data helps you to choose the right model. Data preparation is key in order to make your training set correctly. I know I'm bouncing all over the place. I apologize for that

For instance we might have a logistic regression model and we want to identify the individuals who have a certain condition versus those who don't. The first thing we do is properly prepare our data and then train it (this is the short version) but  my point is training a model is very important it allows your ML model to be able to predict the accuracy of it.

I should say I really enjoy Machine Learning/ Deep Learning but I am no means an expert. I highly recommend this class though its how I started off understanding the fundamentals.

[Coursera Andrew Ng course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning)